# Are code review questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code Golf, Code Review, and similar questions](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/code-golf-code-review-and-similar-questions)

A "code review question" is a question that asks for general ideas on improving a piece of code.  Is it idiomatic? Are there any obvious mistakes or fragile bits?  Could it have been done "better" in some sense of the word?

Feedback like this is always very valuable when learning a new language, or a new area of a system we already know.  There is already [a dedicated StackExchange site for code review questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but Mathematica-related questions are unlikely to receive much attention there.

**The discussion point:** Should questions like these be on topic for our site?  The obvious problem is that for such questions there's usually no clear answer that can be accepted, and their usefulness for future visitors is limited. Do questions like this fit the format of the site?

There was a [question about this before](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/code-golf-code-review-and-similar-questions) but there everyone was focusing on code golf, not on code review, so I think it's worth starting a new discussion.

This post was prompted by a code review question posted a couple of minutes ago:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/question-for-comments-on-a-developed-custom-control

**EDIT:**

- [Here's a related question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/should-so-allow-give-me-some-feedback-questions).

Comment: This really is a duplicate of my previous question.  Please edit it as you see fit.