# Is a question seeking to golf a code on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[This thread](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/136/37848), as far as I understand, makes it clear that code-golf questions are generally off topic. But regarding the top answer, I got the impression that if a question asks to do a specific task and reward the answers based on their code length, then it would be off topic and *maybe* belongs to [somewhere else](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

But suppose that I wrote a piece of Mathematica code and want to improve it, and my improvement criteria is heavily biased towards the code length. In other words, performance is not a concern, nor its readability or simplicity. Quoting a part of @Verbeia's [answer](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/391/37848) in the linked thread:

> I think code review questions should only be allowed where the asker has been specific about how they are looking to improve the code, e.g. faster, more functional style, more concise/readable.

Now what about the code length? Is asking how to golf a code on topic?

Comment: On the one hand, code-golf questions can be an opportunity to present the more esoteric aspects of the Wolfram Language, but I am hesitant to expand the concept of "improved code" to include ignoring performance, readability and simplicity.